# Convert byte array to string spark

Tags: python, arrays, csv, apache-spark, pyspark

I have a csv file which contains multiple fields. There are few fields for which data is coming in byte array format(b'1234'). I want to remove these b'(convert from byte array to string).

I came to know that we can convert byte array to string in two ways.

```
>>> s1 = b'Hi'
>>> s2 = s1.decode('utf-8') 
>>> print(s2)
Hi


>>> s1 = b'Hi'
>>> s2 = str(s1, 'utf-8')
>>> print(s2)
Hi
```

As there so many fields in CSV out of which only few fields contains byte array, I can't directily apply the function to each and every field. I don't have idea of which are are byte array fields and which ate string, int fields.

Any suggestions to convert byte array to string in csv file. I'm trying to do this in spark.

My code snippet :

```
df = sqlContext.read.format('com.databricks.spark.csv').options(header='true', inferschema='true') \
    .option("delimiter", ",")\
    .option("multiLine", "true")\
    .load("file.csv")
```

**Input Data:**

```
b'1234',b'123',Hi,"Hello",b'2FB',b'272',b'4943',b'786',2018-02-19,,Out,768,"Data",b'502',351,
```

As schema changes dynamically we don't have control of knowing which are byte array and which are string. I tried [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40389764/how-to-translate-bytes-objects-into-literal-strings-in-pandas-dataframe-pytho) solution, however it didn't worked for me (it converted all the fields to nan).

Comment: Bad parser usage (`univocity` I think it's all rubbish.)! How data is processed without using the iterator? Why do you use a parser if it is to be subjected to iteration? Deal with your own problem, instead of others ' problems.

Comment: `CSV_BUFF.split("\r\n").pop(0) == univocity` ??

Comment: I updated the code. I just want to point a sample code. However the actual request to byte array to string. I believe parsing won't effect this one. Still removed the that parsing logic.

Comment: You got bad `writing pattern` (if want work with  index,csv never allowed empty element `OR` you want type blank field value try collect data manually(never use a module, a module only suppressed few errors(not all)))

Answer (score 1):

As you said you have a csv file containing bytes as

```
b'1234',b'123',Hi,"Hello",b'2FB',b'272',b'4943',b'786',2018-02-19,,Out,768,"Data",b'502',351,
```

The straight forward solution I see to this is to replace the `b'` and `'` strings with *empty strings* and parse the data to form `dataframe`.

```
rdd = sc.textFile("path to your csv file")\
    .map(lambda x: x.replace("b'", "").replace("'", ""))
```

**Updated**

As @ixaxaar commented

> A better way is to do lambda x: x[2:-1]

So you can just do

```
rdd = sc.textFile("path to your csv file").map(lambda x: x[2:-1])
```

Comment: A better way is to do `lambda x: x[2:-1]`

Comment: Thanks @ixaxaar :) Updated the answer.