# Converting byte objects to int type in python

Tags: python-3.7

I have a dataset where all the numeric variable values are appearing in b'123' byte object form.

I tried the following code: `df['var'].str.decode('utf-8')` But the var becomes NaN for all the data points.

How do I get rid of the `b''` from `b'123'` variable value. My variable types show type object but I need numeric value?

Answer (score 0):

You could try:

```
df['var'] = df['var'].decode('utf-8')
```

Comment: Hi thank you for your response... I tried this but get the following error:  Attribute error: 'Series' object has no attribute 'decode'.

Comment: Mabye have a look at these two links, they might be of help: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40389764/how-to-translate-bytes-objects-into-literal-strings-in-pandas-dataframe-pytho and http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.str.decode.html

Comment: Hi again! Did my last comment help?

Comment: Hi... actually it did not work... I think I have some crazy variable types... but thanks anyways :-)

Comment: Hmm. Mabye try replacing the `utf-8` with `ansi` or another bytecode format.