# pandas string values are not getting proper format

Tags: python, pandas, sas

Before reading into pandas my data looks like in sas dataset

```
Name 
Alfred
Alice
```

After reading into pandas data is getting as

```
Name 
b'Alfred'
b'Alice'
```

Why I am getting the data is different? Steps followed:

1. Import pandas as pd
2. `df=pd.read_sas(r'C:/ProgramData/Anaconda3/Python_local/class.sas7bdat',format='sas7bdat')`

Need your help.

Comment: Please check this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40389764/how-to-translate-bytes-objects-into-literal-strings-in-pandas-dataframe-pytho

Comment: It is actually the same. SAS stores bytes you get bytes. It is only how python present bytes

Answer (score 0):

SAS files need to be imported with special encoding

```
df=pd.read_sas(r'C:/ProgramData/Anaconda3/Python_local/class.sas7bdat',format='sas7bdat', encoding='iso-8859-1')
```