# IS there any regular expression which help to get values in quotes in pandas?

Tags: python, regex, pandas, dataframe

I want to get values out of quotes only. The rest should be NaN.

I have dataframe like this:

```
Col A                 Col B            Col C
b'Ford'               b'VW'              b''
b''                   b'VW'              b''
b''                   b''                b'BMW'
B'Ford'               b''                b''
```

and i want output like this:

**desired output:**

```
Col A                 Col B            Col C
Ford                    VW              NaN 
NaN                     VW              NaN 
NaN                     NaN             BMW
Ford                    NaN             NaN
```

Comment: Just check how to convert bytes to string in pandas. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40389764/how-to-translate-bytes-objects-into-literal-strings-in-pandas-dataframe-pytho

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to translate "bytes" objects into literal strings in pandas Dataframe, Python3.x?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40389764/how-to-translate-bytes-objects-into-literal-strings-in-pandas-dataframe-pytho)

Comment: @jezrael can you help? I tried already other answer but nothing worked.

Answer (score 1):

Not sure why you have those strings as bytes... But one way is with [`DataFrame.applymap`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.applymap.html) and decoding all bytes with `bytes.decode`:

```
df.applymap(bytes.decode)

    Col A Col B Col C
0  Ford    VW      
1          VW      
2               BMW
3  Ford
```

If you want those empty strings as `NaN`:

```
df.applymap(bytes.decode).replace('', float('nan'))

   Col A Col B Col C
0  Ford    VW   NaN
1   NaN    VW   NaN
2   NaN   NaN   BMW
3  Ford   NaN   NaN
```

Comment: `TypeError: ("descriptor 'decode' requires a 'bytes' object but received a 'str'",`