# Pandas read byte string from csv

Tags: python, pandas, tensorflow, types, dtype

I have a pandas dataframe which has byte strings as elements in a column:
E.g. `b'hey'`.

When I write this dataframe to a csv and read if afterwards, pandas will return a
string with the following form `"b'hey'"`.
This is a problem, because when calling `tf.data.Dataset.from_tensor_slices`
the string will be casted to a byte string again and will have the following form:
`b"b'hey'"`.
Specifying the dtype when reading the csv with `dtype = {"COLUMN_NAME":bytes}` didn't to anything.

Has anyone a solution to this without manually changing the string and removing the b?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to translate "bytes" objects into literal strings in pandas Dataframe, Python3.x?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40389764/how-to-translate-bytes-objects-into-literal-strings-in-pandas-dataframe-pytho)

Answer (score 0):

The solution is to apply ast.literal_eval first before decode with 'utf-8'.

To read and convert whole column with byte string:

```
import pandas as pd
import ast
df = pd.read_csv(<YOUR_DATA_FILE>, sep='\t')
df['text'].apply(ast.literal_eval) # assume the column is named with 'text'
df['text'] = df['text'].apply(lambda x: ast.literal_eval(x).decode("utf-8"))
```