# Is there a way to convert complete DataFrames to another datatype?

Tags: python, pandas, string, dataframe, asammdf

I was using the tool asammdf and realized that my DataFrame contains b-strings. I never heard and used that type of string before, however it is causing some problems with my other functions.

Do you know if there is a efficient way to convert my pandas dataframe? Or some other solutions?

The DataFrame looks something like:

```
column1   column2 ...
b'7.00'   b'21.0' ...
b'8.00'   b'22.0' ...
...       ...
```

The DataFrame is being created from asammdf with

```
asammdf.mdf.MDF.to_dataframe()
```

I just choose the channels and groups and usually it creates a perfect DataFrame.

Thank you very much in advance for your help!

So far I tried to store each series astype('float64') in order to calculate with my values.

Comment: Hi! can you give us an exaple of your dataframe? And some code that you tried to use?

Comment: You can try to use something like `df[0] = df[0].astype(float)` for each column

Comment: I tried that, but I don't want anything to be a float. I just want to get rid of the b'x', that would be perfect...

Comment: The `b'x'` is just a way that python use to tell you that the data is store in bytes, so if you need to get rid of the `b` is to convert (decode is the right term) your values. So if you want them to be string you need to `df[0] = df[0].astype(string)` or whatever type you need. If you need more information about the bytestrings you can take a look at [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6224052/what-is-the-difference-between-a-string-and-a-byte-string)

Comment: Okay! But there is no way, I can decode the whole DataFrame at once? Because my case contains each float and string within the DataFrame. Thanks for the similar post!

Comment: Take a look at [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40389764/how-to-translate-bytes-objects-into-literal-strings-in-pandas-dataframe-pytho)